# Part of my jquery is missing!

Tags: jquery

I am using colorbox which I have used many times for different clients, but it is not working this time and I can not figure out why. I am trying to open a video on youtube, and then open up some inline html, I've copied the code from the examples just as I always do, and replaced what needs to be replaced. There are parts of the script that are missing when I look at the source code from the browser.

In my backend it looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:425, innerHeight:344});
    $(".open_colorbox").colorbox({width:"50%", inline:true, href:"#inline_text"});
    });
</script>
```

But when I look at the source code in FF or IE it shows...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".youtube").colorbox();
        $(".open_colorbox").colorbox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like this might be a cacheing issue.  Have you tried emptying all browser and server caches?

Comment: Hold shift and press F5 when you're on the page giving you the issues, then let us know if you're still having the problem.

Comment: Run FF or IE in Private Browsing and you will start fresh with nothing cached.

Comment: Yeah to all, I added more info below

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you...

- Saved the file?
- Linked to the correct javascript in your html file?
- Deployed the application to the right directory?
- Cleared browser and/or server cache?

Comment: have you tried private browsing in firefox to see if your jquery is cached? Ctrl+shft+p

Comment: Yes to all, I've used colorbox for photos on about 8 other clients websites, this is the first time I have tried to use it for youtube and inline text, but I don't see why it would be too different. I have the colorbox folder with the js file, the css, and the images, and linked to them all correctly. To better help here is the website... www.powerhousebowling.com maybe you can see something in the source code.